# Can't open http://localhost:3000 - why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't open http://localhost:3000.

If it's relevant, here is the `rail s` command:

```
Jonass-MBP:first Money$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.6 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2016-09-16 02:31:51] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2016-09-16 02:31:51] INFO  ruby 2.3.1 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-darwin15]
[2016-09-16 02:31:51] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=8906 port=3000
```

Comment: What does your browser says? Have you tried `rails s --port 3001` and fire `http://localhost:3001` in your browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To kill all processes using port 3000 run `kill -9 $(lsof -i tcp:3000 -t)`.